# Command not found when using popen

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, popen

I'm working in C and I have a problem when calling popen with the following  arguments:

```
void exampleFunction(void)
{
    .
    .
    .
    FILE* in = popen("alias -p", "r");
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When I call `popen` this way I get the following message:

```
alias: -p not found
```

I don't know what is actually wrong because when I call `popen` with the following arguments:

```
FILE* in = popen("ls -i", "r");
```

There is no problem and I'm using the same syntax.

Maybe someone realizes what's actually wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `alias` command is built into the shell.

`popen`, like `system()`, invokes `/bin/sh` to execute the specified command. Your interactive shell is probably bash, which supports a `-p` option to `alias`. `/bin/sh`, depending on your system configuration, probably does not.

In any case, even if this worked it wouldn't give you any useful information. The `popen()` call would invoke a new shell, and (again, depending on your configuration), it likely wouldn't have your aliases set up, since it's not an interactive shell.

The `ls -i` command works because `ls` is an external command, so it works the same way regardless of whether it's invoked from `bash` or `/bin/sh`, or from an interactive or non-interactive shell. (Sometimes `ls` can be defined as an alias or shell function, but such definitions typically don't interfere with the use of the `-i` option.)

Answer (score 1):

`alias` is no executable program but a shell built-in (think of it as a "function in bash scripting language") so you can't open a process by this name. You could try to fool bash and pipe it in. Something like this untested snippet:

```
FILE* p = popen("/bin/bash", "r"); // Note: on non-Linux-systems you might need another path or rely on $PATH
fprintf(p, "alias -p\n");
```

Mind that you can't call aliases directly either.
The difference to `ls` is that `ls` exists both, as built-in an as program.

Comment: If you open a pipe with `r` mode, you can't print to it, only read from it. Use the command `/bin/bash -c 'alias -p'`

Comment: Incorrect. `popen()` invokes the command via `/bin/sh`, so for example `popen("alias", "r")` would work (though it probably wouldn't produce any output). The problem is that `/bin/sh`'s `alias` command doesn't support the `-p` option. See my answer.

Comment: This approach assumes you can both feed input to `/bin/bash` and collect its output. That's doable, but not with a simple `pipe()` call. Also, `ls` is not a builtin command in most shells.