# How do I launch SBCL (or arbitrary commands) using popen?

Tags: c, linux, bash, gnome-builder

I'm prototyping a GUI in C, which will trigger functions in a backend written in Lisp. I'm sure there's a more advanced way to do this, but for testing purposes, I wish to execute Lisp commands using the SBCL compiler, launched via the popen function in C.

I followed the instructions on launching Linux commands from within C from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bAAYel7L9o

Yielding the code:

```
int outputter(void){
  FILE *output;
  char buffer[BUFFER];

  output = popen("sbcl", "r");
  if (output == NULL) {
    fputs("POPEN: Failed.\n", stderr);
  }
      else {
        int count = 0;
        while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER-1, output) != NULL) {
            printf("OUTPUT[%d]: %s", count, buffer);
            count ++;
  }
      }
                pclose(output);

  return 0;
}
```

But when I run this function, it tells me: "sh: line 1: sbcl: command not found".

Does anyone have any guidance on successfully running such functions? I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686050/command-not-found-when-using-popen), which suggests that the issue may be to do with whether the shell function is built-in (e.g. ls, not sbcl) or not, but I couldn't determine a way forward from that answer.

Information:

- OS: Fedora 38
- Language: C
- IDE: Gnome Builder
- sh: GNU bash, version 5.2.15 release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

[Command not found when using popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686050/command-not-found-when-using-popen)

Comment: The `sbcl` program is not in your `PATH`. Maybe `sbcl` works from  your interactive shell because you have an alias for it? `ls` is not built into your shell; it's an executable program that is usually `/usr/bin/ls` and `/usr/bin` is usually in `PATH`.

Comment: Firstly, you don't want/need the complexity of `subprocess.Popen()` try instead just to use `subprocess.run()` if possible. Secondly, try running `type sbcl` in your shell to get its full path, then use that in your `subprocess()` call, e.g. `subprocess.run(["/usr/local/bin/sbcl", ...])`

Comment: Thank you both for the help! Regarding the path: I have tried giving popen the path to the executable (/usr/bin/sbcl) and this yields the following error: "sh: line 1: /usr/bin/sbcl: No such file or directory" (I can type this path into my terminal and it will execute just fine.)

Regarding subprocess.run, I can find a Python function but not a C function thus described: please can you point me to the documentation?

Comment: Sure you're not somehow running your program on a different computer/vm/docker instance/etc. than you're using to run sbcl successfully on?

Comment: Interesting: per your question, Shawn, there's no indication that I'm on a virtual machine; however, I got curious and used the method above to launch a terminal: when I navigated to /usr/bin/ (where sbcl is found) it is not there. I can verify that it is there when I access via a regular terminal/file browser, it's just invisible to this terminal. Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: Further, symlinking to sbcl from another directory (e.g. home) yields same error; copying to home yields this error:

fatal error encountered in SBCL pid 16(tid 0x7f092310f740):
can't find core file at /usr/lib/sbcl//sbcl.core